# p4merge tool configuration with git

Tags: git, mergetool

I just configured gittool p4merge on my client server. When I do git mergetool, I get the pop-up for meld instead of p4merge:

{local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
Hit return to start merge resolution tool (meld):

I checked git config file and meld id not configured in .gitconfig.

My .gitconfig file contents are:

```
[merge]
tool = p4merge
[mergetool]
keepBackup = false
[mergetool "p4merge"]
path = /usr/bin/p4merge
```

Why its picking meld instead of p4merge.  Can someone suggest why it’s happening??

Comment: Perhaps it is configured in your repository instead? Do a `git config --list --show-origin`

Comment: I dont see this --show-origin option in the command: git config --list --show-origin
error: unknown option `show-origin'
usage: git config [options]

Comment: Which version of `git` ?

Comment: git version 2.1.0

Comment: OK, then I don't know, inspect the configuration files below `.git` perhaps? You should consider updating. Git 2.1.0 is almost 3 years old.